# prevent redirection or have RequestDispatcher to link to specific tab

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

We made a jsp and sent data to the database through the use of servlet...
however, it redirects to a blank page,,, I would want to either prevent that redirection or have the RequestDispatcher link to a specified tab on my homepage..
how should I do this?

this is the code inside jsp

```
 <nav class="MenuBar rounded-corners clearfix pinned-colelem" id="menuu191"><!-- horizontal box -->
     <div class="MenuItemContainer clearfix grpelem" id="u192"><!-- vertical box -->
      <a class="nonblock nontext MenuItem MenuItemWithSubMenu anim_swing rounded-corners clearfix colelem" id="u193" href="interface.jsp#home"><!-- horizontal box --><div class="MenuItemLabel NoWrap clearfix grpelem" id="u195-4"><!-- content --><p>Home</p></div></a>
     </div>
     <div class="MenuItemContainer clearfix grpelem" id="u222"><!-- vertical box -->
      <a class="nonblock nontext MenuItem MenuItemWithSubMenu anim_swing rounded-corners clearfix colelem" id="u223" href="interface.jspl#enrolment" ><!-- horizontal box --><div class="MenuItemLabel NoWrap clearfix grpelem" id="u224-4"><!-- content --><p>Enrollment</p></div></a>
     </div>
     <div class="MenuItemContainer clearfix grpelem" id="u229"><!-- vertical box -->
      <a class="nonblock nontext MenuItem MenuItemWithSubMenu anim_swing rounded-corners clearfix colelem" id="u230" href="interface.jsp#viewgrades"><!-- horizontal box --><div class="MenuItemLabel NoWrap clearfix grpelem" id="u232-4"><!-- content --><p>Viewing of Grades</p></div></a>
     </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I ask what you have tried in your servlet?

If I understand your question: 
There are two ways to redirect the user to another page, either by using `request.getRequestDispatcher(your_jsp_url).forward(request, response)` in `doGet()`, or by using `response.sendRedirect(a_servlet_url)` to send to another servlet's `doGet()`-method.

Comment: I solved it now,, I mispelled earlier when I tried sendRedirect(),, because of that I searched for other ways,,,, I tried it again and corrected the mispelling and it worked xD...

Comment: I used sendRedirect(servlet_URL); I'll accept your answer anyway